# App as a website launcher

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have a requirement in which i want to make a app that will launch my website and close down. How to achieve this?

```
    package com.example.myappname;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("myweburl"));
        startActivity(myIntent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

My website is opening in browser but app still shows in current open app list .I want to shutdown app as soon as it opens url in browser.

Comment: It's not considered best practice to force close your application.  Move your code to onResume, so that if the user taps on your app from the recent apps list, it will redirect them again.

Comment: i want to just close it.

Comment: try using finish in `onpause`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want your app to not show up in the recent apps list. To do that use the `android:excludeFromRecents` in your manifest for the activity you are launching the website from

```
<activity
        android:name=".Activity"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Read more about the `android:excludeFromRecents` attribute [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#exclude)

Comment: its working. But a blank white screen appears for a moment then browser appears can you please show me some solution or trick to avoid it?

Comment: the blank white screen is your app appearing before it closes. Not sure how to avoid that. A better way would be to create a screen in your app which tells the user what's going on.. something like "Redirecting you the website in 3..2..1.." or better yet.. open the website in your app in a webview itself..

Comment: that's a good idea to show some message screen and then redirect to browser.I don't wanna  use webview. How can i wait for lets say 10 sec and then launch browser.

Comment: new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() { //launch website}, 10*1000);